# Given two dictionaries containing arrays of different capacities add elements to the lesser populated array

Tags: swift, dictionary, functional-programming, immutability, reduce

So given this data

```
var data = 
  ["groupA": 
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   "groupB":
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

I want this output:

```
["groupA":
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
 "groupB": 
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

This is the best answer I was able to come up with but I feel like its lacking as I have access to the accumulator that I want to mutate within the reduce function.

```
let maxElement = data.reduce(data.first!) { (acc, obj) in
  return acc.value.count > obj.value.count ? acc : obj
}

for dict in data {
  if dict.value.count < maxElement.value.count {
    var mutableValues = dict.value
    mutableValues.insert(0, at: 0)
    data[dict.key] = mutableValues
  }
}
```

I think I'm not understanding how to best refactor my reduce function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, like me, you don't like for loops, how about this:

```
data.reduce(data.values.reduce(0){max($0,$1.count)})
{ data[$1.0] = Array(repeating:0,count:$0-$1.1.count) + $1.1; return $0}
```

Comment: Ayyy there it is. Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum count of your arrays and create an array of zeros with the difference to append to the lesser populated arrays as follow:

```
var dict: [String:[Int]] = ["groupA": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                            "groupB": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

let maxCount = dict.values.map{ $0.count }.max() ?? 0
for (key, value) in dict {
    let difference = maxCount - value.count
    if difference > 0 {
        dict[key] =  repeatElement(0, count: difference) + value
    }
}


print(dict)    // ["groupB": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], "groupA": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: You could also say `let maxCount = data.values.map{$0.count}.max() ?? 0` for the max count. Also I would use a `for ... in` loop here, as you can do `for (key, value) in dict {...}`. Also also you can say `repeatElement(0, count: difference)` for the prefixed zeroes, which saves allocating a temporary array buffer.

Comment: @Hamish do you think using map for the count it is faster than the syntax I have now?

Comment: The `map(_:)` is applied to `dict.values` which is a lazy collection, therefore the map is evaluated lazily – so there shouldn't really be any performance difference (no temporary array created at least). I only really suggested it for a slightly nicer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you need to refactor your code for the reduce function, I did it the following way.

Hope this helps,

```
let maxElement = data.reduce(data.first!) {
    $0.value.count > $1.value.count ? $0 : $1
}
```

further I modified the code you provided to achieve the results you were trying.

and the code worked well for me.

```
let maxElement = data.reduce(data.first!) {
    $0.value.count > $1.value.count ? $0 : $1
}

let minElement = data.reduce(data.first!) {
    $0.value.count < $1.value.count ? $0 : $1
}

for dict in data {
    if dict.value.count < maxElement.value.count {
        var mutableValues = minElement.value
        let arrayOfZeros = Array(repeating: 0, count: maxElement.value.count - minElement.value.count)
        mutableValues.insert(contentsOf: arrayOfZeros, at: 0)
        data[dict.key] = mutableValues
    }
}
```